# Why Can't I merge two curved paths in InDesign CS5?

Tags: adobe-indesign, shapes, path, pathfinder, text-on-path

I'm using **InDesign CS5** at work and I'm trying to create a "U", "Horseshoe", or "shield" curved path for text to follow.

I already know how to copy+paste text on a path. That is not the issue. The issue is this:

In order to make a perfect horseshoe-like shape I want to make on half of my shape first then duplicate, flip horizontally and merge. But, every time I try to merge the two hockey-stick like shapes, ***InDesign tries to force the shape closed***. I'm not trying to make a closed shape. I want a "U" (an no, using an actual letter U won't work for this example).

Once I have successfully joined the paths I will then put my text on the resulting path.

This is a fairly straightforward task, but I have included this helpful illustration for clarification:

**InDesign CS5 doesn't join curved paths correctly (Graphic by Eric Hepperle, 2020):**

[image: InDesign CS5 doesn't join curved paths correctly (Graphic by Eric Hepperle, 2020)]

Of course I did my research. This 4-year old post was the closest I found to anyone mentioning this problem, and though it is for ILLUSTRATOR not INDESIGN I held out hope. But, alas none of the solutions nor comments got me any closer to a fix:

[Why can't I merge two points?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/47224/why-cant-i-merge-two-points)

Why is this basic process so hard and how can I get it done?

Comment: Why not create a closed path and then delete the bottom segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do works better for closed, not open, paths. Try this:

- Hit <kbd>A</kbd>
- Click and drag to select both points at the top where the shapes meet
- Go to 'Object → Paths → Join'
- Repeat for the lower ends of the shapes (the points at the bottom of the shapes)

Comment: Thanks, Lucian. I will try that when I get a chance.

Comment: Finally got around to trying this out. It worked with one exception: immediately before this Align > Distribute Spacing > 0 pt to make the two halves come together as close as possible (otherwise it will draw an extra segment because it doesn't automatically "magnet" the two sides together). Marked as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Select the Two Anchor Points Meeting at same Place with Direct Selection Tool
Step 2 : Go to Object -> Path -> Join

It will solve your query for more details go to this video Link
https://youtu.be/vTvO7cS9oVM

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the two vector paths aligned, then highlight the two bezier handles you want to join, then cmd+j to join them. ("Object" menu, then "Join")